# getLoginStatus() not getting response in firefox/ie

Tags: facebook, firefox

The following code does not seem to work in Firefox or IE, but runs fine in Chrome. I'm hoping someone might have some insight into what I am doing wrong. It is used to run a unity game in the Facebook canvas.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var appID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var connected = false;
var loggedin = false;
var purchaseResult = "Failed";
var inviteResult = "Failed";

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
// init the FB JS SDK
FB.init({
  appId      : appID, // App ID from the App Dashboard
  status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
  cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
  oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
  frictionlessRequests : true,
  xfbml      : false  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
});

// Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
//Get the current login status.
document.getElementById("text").innerText = "Getting login status";
console.log("Getting login status");
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      console.log("got response");
      var user_box = document.getElementById("login");
      //document.getElementById("text").innerText = "Got response: " + response.status;
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    console.log("Getting login status returned user id: " + uid);
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    //user_box.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    loggedin = true; 
    //document.write("Connected to facebook");
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
    user_box.style.display = 'block';
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      // Let unity know the user has logged in
      GetCurrentUser();
      user_box.style.display = 'none';
    });
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      // Let unity know the user has logged in
      GetCurrentUser();
      user_box.style.display = 'none';
    });
    user_box.style.display = 'block';
  }

  if (loggedin) {
    GetCurrentUser();
  }
}, true);
};
```

I have log messages in there to check what's going on, but it's only in Chrome that I get any messages after "Getting login status".

Thanks,
Andrew.

Answer (score 0):

Try your `Additional initialization code` inside this-

```
if (typeof(FB) != 'undefined' && FB != null )
{

    // your code

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Adding that resulted in no log messages from firefox/ie but nothing changed in chrome. So it appears as if firefox/ie isn't getting the FB object. Not too sure why though.